# Why is sum-type a disjunction in the Curry-Howard correspondence?

Tags: category-theory, curry-howard

According to the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#General_formulation) the sum-type aka tagged-union is the equivalent of disjunction, logical OR

Why is this the case? Is it not closer to XOR? `(a or b)` implies that it could be `a` or `b` or `both`, whereas `Either a b` must be `a` or `b` but never both.

Answer (score 2):

Curry-Howard correspondence says that an element of `Either a b` represents a *proof* of `a or b`. To prove a disjunction it's enough to prove (provide an element of) `a` or `b`. You do this by constructing `Either a b` using either `Left a` or `Right b`.